# How do I store the number of observations in a data frame into a variable?

Tags: r

If I have a data frame with *n* obs, how do I assign *n* to a variable?

e.g
`x <- obscount(dataframe)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want `nrow`:

```
nrow(dataframe)
```